# Javascript sorting dates in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, datetime

I can't figure out why Javascript (running in Chrome, Safari, or NodeJS) seemingly sorts these dates incorrectly:

```
> [
      "2014-05-01T08:06:00.000Z",
      "2014-05-01T06:26:00.000Z",
      "2014-05-01T06:27:00.000Z"
  ].map(function(x) {return new Date(x)}).sort()
```

produces

```
[ Thu May 01 2014 01:06:00 GMT-0700 (PDT),
  Wed Apr 30 2014 23:26:00 GMT-0700 (PDT),
  Wed Apr 30 2014 23:27:00 GMT-0700 (PDT) ]
```

I have looked for odd time changes around that date but can't find any.

Comment: Produces result values are not there in input array..

Comment: Voting to close for: `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.` Behavior is clearly documented for method in question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks. I had also used a comparator before posting, but I realize now I had a mistake in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply calling [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method will basically sorting based on string comparison. So for sorting based on date object use custom sort function.

```js
console.log(
  [
    "2014-05-01T08:06:00.000Z",
    "2014-05-01T06:26:00.000Z",
    "2014-05-01T06:27:00.000Z"
  ].map(function(x) {
    return new Date(x)
  }).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  })
)
```

---

If you want to sort the original array then avoid [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method and inside the compare function parse the date string before taking difference.

```js
console.log(
  [
    "2014-05-01T08:06:00.000Z",
    "2014-05-01T06:26:00.000Z",
    "2014-05-01T06:27:00.000Z"
  ].sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date(a) - new Date(b);
  })
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind answer! I feel rather dumb missing what now what seems obvious as I re-read the spec, but I was definitely on the wrong track until I posted here.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to use a < operator instead of a - operator and getting strange results.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.sort` takes a callback which can return `negative`, `positive` or `zero` value to sort the target array.

```
[
   "2014-05-01T08:06:00.000Z",
   "2014-05-01T06:26:00.000Z",
   "2014-05-01T06:27:00.000Z"
].sort(function(a, b){
    return (new Date(b) - new Date(a));
})
```